# sox: A-law to PCM

Tags: sox

How can I convert an A-law wave file to PCM? I have tried several options already with sox, but the output always stays A-law. For your information, here's the complete specification of the file I'm trying to convert.

```
<me@comp:~> file a.wav
a.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, ITU G.711 A-law, stereo 8000 Hz
```

Thanks in advance,

Joris

Answer (score 4):

The usual way to do it would be:

```
sox a.wav -e signed-integer pcm.wav
```